# JSON to PHP Associative array

Tags: php, json, facebook, associative-array

would any of you know a good way to put this into an associative array . I have tried [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) but found it to not be much help.

This is the data i need to put into an associative array:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Joe Bloggs",
      "id": "203403465"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fred Bloggs",
      "id": "254706567"
    },
    {
      "name": "Barny Rubble",
      "id": "453363843"
    },
    {
      "name": "Homer Simpson",
      "id": "263508546"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

After I accepted the answer, I remembered why I thought that the json_decode wasn't working.

Instead of having an associative array like this:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [name] => Joe Bloggs
    [id] => 203403465
)
```

I wanted one like this:

```
Array
(
    [Joe Bloggs] => 45203340465
    [Fred Bloggs] => 65034033446
)
```

Unfortunately, I had forgotten this at the time.. but I have resolved my issue now anyway.

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: just in case ... it's not allowed to store facebook-user data except the uid longer than 24 hours ...

Comment: @helle: that's no longer the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i asume your json comes via ajax.... (otherwise the code works with json_decode)
so be sure the js json stringifys your object and

you'll need to stripslashes before json_decode ;-) in php

Comment: It doesn't come via AJAX but for some reason, now when I use json_decode it works as i initally expected it to. Very strange because when I remove stripslashes, it also works... maybe I messed something up when I previously tried it. Many Thanks helle for nudging me back on track :o)

Answer (score 10):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) works for me on your data:

```
print_r(json_decode('{
       "data": [
          {
             "name": "Joe Bloggs",
             "id": "203403465"
          },
          {
             "name": "Fred Bloggs",
             "id": "254706567"
          },
          {
             "name": "Barny Rubble",
             "id": "453363843"
          },
          {
             "name": "Homer Simpson",
             "id": "263508546"
          }
       ]
    }
', true));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Joe Bloggs
                    [id] => 203403465
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Fred Bloggs
                    [id] => 254706567
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Barny Rubble
                    [id] => 453363843
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Homer Simpson
                    [id] => 263508546
                )

        )

)
```

Setting the second argument to `true` returns an associative array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer webbiedave, if you view my last comment on helle's comment you'll see what I did. +1 for the response I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a new array

```
$json_array = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
$assoc_array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json_array); $i++)
{
     $key = $json_array[$i]['name'];
     $assoc_array[$key] = $json_array[$i]['value'];
}
```

you will get your associative array in $assoc_array and you can now directly access using indexes.

Comment: That's what I needed.