# Get value from an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

My echo output is below - NOTE: This comes from a Joomla module echo statement - Output of a repeatable field.

$params->get('star_slides');

```
{"Field1":["/demo/slide1.jpg","/demo/slide2.jpg"],"Field2":["Content 1","Content 2"],"Field 3":["Content 3","Content 4"]}
```

My goal is to extract the individual values of the fields

Set 1 - Values of the first field set.

```
/demo/slide1.jpg 
Content 1 
Content 3
```

How can I do this using php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON to PHP Associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073205/json-to-php-associative-array)

Comment: Steve - This is not a duplicate - This comes from a Module parameter echo statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON string to object or array, then you can access it's values. Like this:

```
<?php
$json = '{"Field1":["/demo/slide1.jpg","/demo/slide2.jpg"],"Field2":["Content 1","Content 2"],"Field 3":["Content 3","Content 4"]}';
$parsed = json_decode($json, true);
echo $parsed['Field1'][0];
echo "\n";
echo $parsed['Field2'][0];
echo "\n";
echo $parsed['Field 3'][0];
echo "\n";
?>
```

It outputs:

```
/demo/slide1.jpg
Content 1
Content 3
```

[Link to demo on Codepad.](http://codepad.org/KpkcgfUs)

Comment: Not sure who is voting down your answer -  Your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Strange rules here - I am not allowed to Vote Up. I am relatively new here and dont have enough points to vote.