# PHP json_decode to associative array

Tags: php, json

I have just been bashing my head against a brick wall for several hours trying to use the `json_decode()` function in PHP. The same problem has appeared on Stack Overflow *many* times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073205/json-to-php-associative-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813007/json-php-decode-not-working).

The solution was that, [as stated in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), if you want to get an associative array from a JSON object, you need to include a second, optional `true` parameter in your function call, like this:

```
$assoc_array = json_decode($the_JSON,true);
```

On the other hand, leaving this parameter out returns an object instead:

```
$php_objest = json_decode($the_JSON);
```

This is most annoying for me because it's a problem I've solved before some time ago, but forgot.

Do people agree that having this defaulting to `true` rather than `false` reflects the majority of use-cases?

*Edit: As requested below, the use-case that caused this error (similar to what I've done in the past) was trying to decode a JSON object, add/re-arrange some values, and then re-encode. A code example is:*

```
$the_hardcoded_json_string = "{\"a\":60,\"vi\":0,\"is\":0}";
$the_associative_array = json_decode( $the_hardcoded_json_string, true );
$the_associative_array["c"] = 758;
$the_new_json_string = json_encode( $the_associative_array );
```

Comment: No - can you expand on why this would want a `false` parameter?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little like how you encoding and decoding? If possible plz provide code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right place here to discuss php's default parameters but if i like to change it i would do it like this:

```
function my_json_decode($json, $assoc=true, $depth=512, $options=0) {
    return json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth, $options);
}
```

I hope i understood your question correctly. Please correct me if i don't. I am not shure if the majority of use-cases need the assoc-argument set to `true`. But I fear there will be a lot of trouble if they change it to `true` right now, because a lot of code needs to be rewritten.